# Syntax error uploading a .sql file in the Command Line

Tags: mysql, sql, database, command-line

In the Command Line I created a database with:

```
create database mysql;
```

but when i try to upload a database file with the command:

```
mysql -u root -p  database < dbdump.sql;
```

i receive a syntax error and i don't understand where i'm wrong

```
ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'mysql
 -u root -p  database < dbdump.sql' at line 1
```

Comment: post the error msg so that we can help you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. confirm you're running the command from a shell and not from mysql.
2. I recall needing to be in mysql.exe directory when running such commands
3. remove the spaces around <. Ie, write `mysql -u root -p  database<dbdump.sql`

Comment: I wasn't in the shell and i didn't run the command in the right folder. Thanks a lot!